# dynamically rendering plain .html page on webmatrix

Tags: html, webmatrix

I'm trying to render a .html webpage using `@Renderpage()` method in Webmatrix but the .html extension is not supported by the method. I guess the method only supports cshtml extensions. Is there a way I can render html pages dynamically on my site (Webmatrix). I dont want to use an iframe because I'll definitely have issues with my jquery files.

I attempted something i feel is safe yet feels unsafe. I resolved to read the html file and inject it to the DOM manually using:

```
Array html = null;
var mypage = Server.MapPath(page);
if(File.Exists(mypage)){
    html = File.ReadAllLines(mypage);
}
```

After reading the file.....i injected it to the DOM

```
        <div class="s_content s fontfix left s_content2 downdown">
            @foreach (var data in html) { 
                <text>@Html.Raw(data)</text>
            }
        </div>
```

All this runs on compilation time before the page is created for rendering.....I attempted some security measures by attempting to inject server-side C# code in the HTML file but was useless. Makes me feel safe atleast. Is this risky? What is the possible threat to this alternative. i wish i can still have an alternative proper solution from the house. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @Renderpage() doesn't support HTML files, why don't you try Jquery.load or Ajax. There are lots of tutorials based on dynamic loading of html content.

Comment: @abdhoms.....there are two problems with ur suggestion. Jquery load would cost me another http request after document.ready (). Secondly, I'm gonna hav issues wit my object bindings based on events. Its like the regular issue wit clone ur dom. Thanks though!!!! I need a server side solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar but I don't use @Renderpage or an html file. Instead I am using the "onclick" event and a javascript function which opens a cshtml file. You just put this and the java script function in your main cshtml file in the hmtl section. It will open a file in the current directory called my_window.cshtml when clicked

```
<a onclick=openWin("my_window",700,850);>Open when clicked</a>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openWin(url, width, height)
    {
        myWindow=window.open(url,'_blank','width='+width+',height='+height);
        myWindow.focus();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Thomas....ur suggestion would cost me another http request and my object event binding would fail after injecting the html page. Thirdly, I need the resulting page as one just like @ rendersection () not on a seperate blank page on an event. I need a server side solution while the page is being compiled